# Using jQuery 'this' with a selector of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry jQuery noob question here, I am attempting to make all of the div elements with the class .thumbnail clickable with a callback function. But, once one of the div(s) of that class is clicked I need the specific ID of that given div so I can do further manipulation to that specific one.  I am confused if I would use 'this' to reference that specific div once it is clicked or if I am looking at this the wrong way.

Im sure this is a very simple question for you jQuery gurus to answer, its been a long day and my brain is completely zombified.

Example Sudo Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".thumbnail").click(function() {

        //need to get id of thumbnail that was clicked, this is where I am confused       
        var thumbnail_id = $(this).attr('id')
        alert(thumbnail_id);

     });

});

</script>

<div class=thumbnail" id="1">Tom</div>
<div class=thumbnail" id="2">Jerry</div>
<div class=thumbnail" id="3">Sue</div>
<div class=thumbnail" id="4">Mary</div>
<div class=thumbnail" id="5">Brian</div>
```

Comment: You are doing it right.

Comment: Id's shouldn't start with number previous to HTML5. Make sure your browser supports this.

Comment: Along the same lines as elclanrs, if you need to use integers, store them in a `data attribute`. Use like `class="thumbnail" data-id="1"`

Comment: Not that it matters massively, but you are missing a ; from your function.

Comment: Is your real problem the missing quotes in the `class="thumbnail"` or is that just an accident in typing up your question and you were really asking about using `this` in the click handler?

Comment: Come on @korono89.  Where are you?  17 hours later and you're not around to clarify whether your sole problem is missing quotes or whether you really wanted to know about `this` in the event handler.  That's not cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what your jQuery problem is.  To address the question you're asking, when an object is clicked in your code, the `click` handler will be called and `this` will be set to the DOM element that was clicked on.  This works if there is one object with the thumbnail class or many.

If your problem is really that your HTML is in error, then you should add the missing quote to change this:

```
<div class=thumbnail" ...
```

to this:

```
<div class="thumbnail" ...
```

FYI, a better way to do this is as follows.  This fixes the quote problem and uses a data attribute rather than a numeric id value:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8tczB/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
        //need to get id of thumbnail that was clicked, this is where I am confused       
        var thumbnail_id = $(this).data('id');
        alert(thumbnail_id);
     });
});
</script>

<div class="thumbnail" data-id="1">Tom</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-id="2">Jerry</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-id="3">Sue</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-id="4">Mary</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-id="5">Brian</div>
```

Comment: Geez - I answer the actual question they asked and I get two immediate downvotes.  Come on people.  It's not like they gave us a working piece of code we could see what the real issue was here.  How do you know the missing quote wasn't just an error in their question and I've answered their real question.  Why does a well intentioned answer here get downvotes.  Nobody else actually attempted to answer the question they asked.

Comment: Disagree completely, your first answer (before edits, which is the first paragraph in your current answer) is not an answer, should have been a comment.

Comment: @JackPettinger - it was an answer to the question that was asked.  The operative part of the question was this: `" I am confused if I would use 'this' to reference that specific div once it is clicked or if I am looking at this the wrong way."`.  That's what I answered.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 that was exactly wht i needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

DOnt you think thumbnail should be written like `"thumbnail"` and not `thumbnail"`